# Double type parsing error in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, double, decimal

this is my code and i get this error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

```
var variable1= double.Parse("0.03".ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

but for this code i didn't get error:

```
var variable1= double.Parse("0.03",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

what's the reason?

Comment: This doesn't throws exception. Are you looking for `var sss = double.Parse("0.03", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` ?

Comment: i checked that, i should describe my question more

Comment: @SonerGönül: It may not throw an exception for *you*, but it will throw an exception if the current culture doesn't use `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: @JonSkeet But it uses `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` before he parse it. And InvariantCulture's decimal seperator isn't `.`  ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: That's passing the `CultureInfo` into the `ToString` method, which is pointless as calling `ToString` *on a string* isn't going to do anything. That doesn't change which culture is used for *parsing*, does it? Basically David's answer nails it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"0.03".ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

evaluates to `"0.03"`

Looking at this expression in isolation you can see that something is wrong. Why are you calling `ToString()` on a string? Calling [`ToString()` on a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tostring.aspx) simply returns the original string.

Anyway, moving on. Your function call is therefore the same as

```
double.Parse("0.03")
```

And that probably results in an error because your local decimal separator is not `"."`.

You meant to write

```
double.Parse("0.03", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
double.Parse("0.03", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

[Double.Parse Method (String, NumberStyles)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)